# how to do prod build in ionic capacitor

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, ionic-native

In ionic 4, how to do a release aka prod build?

The angular part can be build in prod mode by `ionic build --prod`

Now how to copy this build to android? If I do `ionic capacitor run android` it will do normal build first and then copy assets to android. But I want to build in prod mode and take assets to android.

(I know how to generate apk in Android studio)

Answer (score 8):

After doing
`ionic build --prod`

Assuming you have already installed Capacitor, otherwise you can follow [this](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/getting-started) and thereafter,
You can do the following

`npx cap copy android`

Which copies the built code to android folder.

Then you can do

`npx cap open android`

Which opens android studio if you havent opened it already, then you should go to `Build` -> `Generate Signed Bundle / APK` option and the rest is quite straightforward.

[image]

More info can be found [here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/basics/building-your-app)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the simple way.**

```
ionic capacitor build android --prod
```

after the command, the android studio will open automatic

> Development:
> *`android stdio: Build-> Build Bundle(s)/APK(s)->Build APk(s)`*
>
> Production:        *`android stdio: Build-> Generate Signed Bundle(s)/APK(s)-> Android App Bundle or APk-> release`*

Comment: not opening android studio but getting the below error message
ionic capacitor build android --prod
[ERROR] Unable to find command: capacitor build android

Comment: This error message occurs because your project is based on Cordova and not capacitor